# Laravel 8 - Get Data One to Many Relation

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I Have Problem with get data

This is my code
Controller

```
$class = DetailMentor::with('Kelas')->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Model:

```
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_mentor';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'id_kelas',
    ];

    public $timestamps = true;

    public function Kelas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Kelas::class, 'id_kelas','id_kelas');
    }

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id','id');
```

View index

```
 <tbody>
                                     
 @forelse ($class->Kelas as $item)
 <tr role="row" class="odd">
   <th scope="row" class="small" class="sorting_1">{{ $loop->iteration}}.</th>
   <td>{{ $item->nama_kelas }}</td>
   <td>{{ $item->Jeniskelas->jenis_kelas }}</td>
   <td>{{ $item->level->nama_level }}</td>
   <td class="text-center">
       @if ($item->status_video == 'Telah Dibuat')
          <span class="badge badge-success ">Telah Dibuat</span>
       @else
          <span class="badge badge-danger">Belum Dibuat</span>
       @endif
   </td>
   </tr>
 @empty
                                        
 @endforelse
                                        
</tbody>
```

Error:
Property [Kelas] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\laragon\www\Bootcamp\resources\views\mentor\listkelas\index.blade.php)

I want to group data kelas by id. If i use `first` it only takes one data, If i use get it say error. Can someone Helpme, Please! I'm new to this

[Picture: Array Return $class][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fjIj.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first ensure if the data get correctly test it on **postman** or on **browser** you can use method `dd()`
so if the data come correct

the problem in view `index.blade.php`
I think it works on `first` method because you get one object (one record)

and it doesn't work for `get` method because it gets array of object so the way of display this array it is different from the one object

ensure the way of display it and use `foreach in index.blade.php`

hopefully that is help you

**update:**

```
        @foreach ($class as $item)
         <tr role="row" class="odd">
         <th scope="row" class="small" class="sorting_1">{{ $loop->iteration}}.</th>
         <td>{{ $item->kelas[0]->nama_kelas }}</td>
         <td>{{ $item->kelas[0]->Jeniskelas->jenis_kelas }}</td>
         <td class="text-center">
       @if ($item->kelas[0]->status_video == 'Telah Dibuat')
          <span class="badge badge-success ">Telah Dibuat</span>
       @else
          <span class="badge badge-danger">Belum Dibuat</span>
       @endif
   </td>
   </tr>
                                                               
     @empty

     @endforeach
```

you can access like this `$item->kelas[0]->nama_kelas`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fjIj.png (This is picture with dd() function to show data), can you help me sir, on my question I've edited contains view

Comment: check the update of the answer

Comment: Thank you sir, its work . Thank you so much God bless you !!